# Is there a way to ssh into a machine without password / key, but with the host permission?

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to try and ssh into a machine, and instead of being prompted for a password, the host (currently logged in user) will be prompted: do you allow  to login?

What I'm trying to do is to help someone with basic installations on his machine, but I don't want to have his key / password (to not compromise him)

Comment: If they can copy and paste a command, have them append your SSH public key to their `.ssh/authorized_keys` file

Comment: Or have them create a (temporary) new user for you

Comment: @roaima but that would give me full access to their machine - which means compromise

Comment: Perhaps you should amend your question to explain more about how you intend to "_help someone with basic installations on his machine_" if you don't want to login to their machine

Comment: @roaima I thought it was sufficiently explained. I want to login. I don't want to have any way to re-login after that. that's why I want the host to allow me in (one time), instead of me entering a password. I guess the host can add me to the ssh keys, and then remove me...

Comment: Well yes, of course

Comment: If you can install software on that machine, you have root privileges. This means that even if you are allowed to log in only once, you can easily reconfigure the system to allow you access later.

Comment: @berndbausch well, not really - I meant more like pip install and such which does not require sudo. Also, I thought of asking host to enter password each time I need sodu (working together in tmux)

Comment: I guess it's technically possible with [`pam_exec`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15640994/10765659), although IMO a person who needs help with "basic installations" should probably leave PAM alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange request and I wonder who's concerned about the "compromise" (you or them).

If they are concerned about compromise and you are looking for a way to tell them *"it'll be safe because..."* it's unlikely you'll find something to convince them.  If they don't want you on their system then limiting yourself to just one login is unlikely to help.  ***What's to stop you installing your SSH key during your one login?***

If you are looking for a way to "be nice" and ensure you don't accidentally open up a back door into their machine then you can use public/private keys and delete your public key from `authorized_keys` when you're done.  They can even check you've done this when you've finished.

---

## Enabling access for just a single login.

I've not used this before so can't offer a step-by-sep guide on how to.  But the I'll point you at the pieces:

There's a PAM module called [pam_oath](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pam_oath) which autogenerates one time passwords.  Typically you would use this for "Two Factor Authentication".  Often you would use a phone app (eg: [google authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=en_GB&gl=US)) to generate the passwords based on a secret key.   **The user logging in doesn't need to be given the secret to generate new passwords, just one password generated from it.**

Openssh server supports PAM authentication for user-password if [UsePAM](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) is enabled.

There's a reference here on how to enable this for just one user:  https://serverfault.com/a/758119/94158

Comment: I indeed only try to be nice...